# How to build a Django QuerySet to check conditions on two manyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models (simplified):

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)  

class ResourceFlow(models.Model):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, related_name="flow")
    amount = models.IntegerField()

class Workflow(models.Model):    
    inputs = models.ManyToManyField(ResourceFlow, related_name="workflow")

class Stock(models):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, related_name="stock")
    amount = models.IntegerField()    

class Producer(models.Model):   
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow, related_name="location")
    stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, related_name="location")
```

I would like to test **with computation done by the the DB engine** if I can start a production.

A production can start if I have enough stock: for my *Producer's workflow*, all *inputs* *ResourcesFlow* *amount* have to be present in the *Producer'stocks*

So the queryset might be one those result:

- for a given producer return all stocked resources that do not fulfill Workflow inputs amounts conditions
- for a given producer return inputs resources needed for the workflow that are not in sufficient quantity in its stocks

It is possible to do that in Django? And if yes how to do it?

Comment: It should be doable, but it's not going to be easy, and you've got a lot of tables in play so you should certainly look to cache these queries. I can't find docs for it, but when you're using an M2M you can query through the tables. For example I've got a `Package` model with an `events` M2M field. On that I can do `Package.events.through.objects.filter(event_id=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've found the answer but anyways, hope I understand your question correctly.

Let's assume we have the following resources:

```
head = Resource.objects.create(name="head")
neck = Resource.objects.create(name="neck")
body = Resource.objects.create(name="body")
arm = Resource.objects.create(name="arm")
leg = Resource.objects.create(name="leg")
```

And we have a `build_a_robot` workflow:

```
build_a_robot = Workflow.objects.create()
build_a_robot.inputs.add(ResourceFlow.objects.create(resource=head, amount=1))
build_a_robot.inputs.add(ResourceFlow.objects.create(resource=neck, amount=1))
build_a_robot.inputs.add(ResourceFlow.objects.create(resource=body, amount=1))
build_a_robot.inputs.add(ResourceFlow.objects.create(resource=arm, amount=2))
build_a_robot.inputs.add(ResourceFlow.objects.create(resource=leg, amount=2))
```

And finally, we have a `producer`:

```
producer = Producer.objects.create(workflow=build_a_robot)
producer.stocks.add(Stock.objects.create(resource=head, amount=0))
producer.stocks.add(Stock.objects.create(resource=neck, amount=3))
producer.stocks.add(Stock.objects.create(resource=body, amount=1))
producer.stocks.add(Stock.objects.create(resource=arm, amount=10))
producer.stocks.add(Stock.objects.create(resource=leg, amount=1))
```

We want to find the list of resources that we have run out of to build a robot given `producer`.

I think here's one way to do it:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

required_resources = ResourceFlow.objects.filter(pk__in=producer.workflow.inputs.values("pk")).values("resource")
required_amount = producer.workflow.inputs.filter(resource=OuterRef("resource")).values("amount")[:1]
missing_stocks = Stock.objects.filter(resource_id__in=required_resources).filter(amount__lt=required_amount)
```

In this example, `missing_stocks` will be equal to:

```
<QuerySet [<Stock: Stock [Resource [head], 0]>, <Stock: Stock [Resource [leg], 1]>]>
```

So, we need more head and leg to build a robot.